# Mocking for requests.Session.get

Tags: python, django, mocking

I have a new management command that grabs a csv from a url and saves it locally, then does some stuff with it afterward and deletes it. Here's where I retrieve it in my "download code":

```
url = 'http://blahblahblah/output.csv'
with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(url)
csv = open('temp_fallback.csv', 'wb')
csv.write(download.content)  # this works for url tests but not mock
csv.close()
```

It's working great for the real url, and things are peachy. I wrote a couple unit tests calling my management command and they're working, but now I'm adding a unit test to use a mocked response instead of hitting the live url. I'm trying it like so, where I'm hoping to substitute what happens for requests.Session.get):

```
@patch('requests.Session.get')
def test_mock_pass(self, mock_response):
    """ Test using mock response """
        
    test_response = {
        'content': 'bunch_of_content_here'
        'status_code': 200,
        'encoding': 'ISO-8859-1',
        'reason': 'OK',
        'elapsed': 'OK'
    }

    mock_response.return_value = test_response
    print("mock_response.return_value['content'] has: ", mock_response.return_value['content'])

    try:
        call_command('download_fallback_csv')
    except CommandError as e:
        self.fail("Failed download csv. {}".format(e))
```

**But something is different between the response I get when calling the url vs the response I'm trying to mock**:

- the tests work fine that use the url, but this mocked test fails during the csv.write with: "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'content'"
- However, I can see the contents from inside my test when I use the "subscriptable" notation: mock_response.return_value['content'])
- If I try to update my "download code" to use csv.write(download.meta['content']), I get a TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable, mock: KeyError: 'meta'

I feel like one bit of code has a slightly different format than the other needs, but I'm not sure how to fix it- where's the missing link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing a `dict` you can pass an object as `test response`. Like the following,

```
@patch('requests.Session.get')
def test_mock_pass(self, mock_response):
    """ Test using mock response """
    
    class TestResponse:
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.__dict__ = kwargs

    test_response = TestResponse(**{
        'content': 'bunch_of_content_here',
        'status_code': 200,
        'encoding': 'ISO-8859-1',
        'reason': 'OK',
        'elapsed': 'OK'
    })

    mock_response.return_value = test_response
    print("mock_response.return_value['content'] has: ", mock_response.return_value.content)

    try:
        call_command('download_fallback_csv')
    except CommandError as e:
        self.fail("Failed download csv. {}".format(e))
```

In that way, you don't have to change the code in the management command.